# What's the meaning of "giving this two blocks"?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In *Bombshell* (2019), Fox News Anchor Gretchen speaks on TV:

> Gretchen: I can't let you go without talking about Donald Trump.

Megyn speaks to Fox News CEO Roger:

> Megyn: Gretchen's **giving this two blocks**? It's that far down the food
>   chain?

Comment: kind of like time slot = block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A show on these kind of news networks [consist of "blocks"](https://www.reddit.com/r/Journalism/comments/3rohjw/what_are_the_blocks_of_a_newscast/).

> **Blocks are just the chunks of the show separated by the commercial breaks.** They're designated by letter. A half hour show might have 3 or 4 blocks (A, B, C, D) and an hour long show could go up to F or G (or more!). How long they are depends on how long your breaks are and how many you have. Generally the A block is all your top stories, B block might be weather or a feature, same with C block. If your show is a full hour, you might do a "reset" with more hard stories in the C or D block (depending on which one falls at the :30 mark in your show).

That Gretchen dedicates two blocks to this incident indicates that she (or rather her producers, or even the network) feels it is rather important.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation that Gretchen feels the segment is important enough to merit two 'blocks' of time but how does that reconcile with Megyn's second sentence? AFAIK, something **up** the food chain is more important than something **down** the food chain. Megyn uses the latter, seemingly contradicting herself.

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah, that's what I'm also confused by.